# Routing in MVC, "Specify a root relative path with a leading '/'"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I had a razor page called Submit that was giving me a `Value cannot be null. Parameter name : viewData` error so I removed the `@page` at the top of my code as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917232/argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-viewdata) post directed. My issue now is that when I load the page I the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'Index' can only be used while executing a Razor Page.  Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page. If you are using LinkGenerator then you must provide the current HttpContext to use relative pages.>

I want my page to have a URL of `https://localhost:44369/Submit` How would I do this? Here is my routing in my Startup.cs file:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
     {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because of incorrect syntax. In one of your Razor Views, you probably have an anchor tag that might look like:

```
<a asp-page="Index">Index</a>
```

That syntax (without the forward slash /)is meant for a Razor Page. In the Razor View, prefix the Page name with a forward slash:

```
<a asp-page="/Index">Index</a>
```

If everything else is correct you should be able to browse https://localhost:44369/Submit and it should show the whatever is written in your Submit page

Comment: Thank you, I had an asp-page hidden deep in a div that was causing the error. I changed it and it worked, I can't believe I didn't see/do this earlier., I spent a depressing amount of time trying to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You might use Razor Pages `asp-action` in a MVC project.
[image]

**For MVC**
1> Using  tag `asp-action` but not `asp-page` to redirect.

```
<a asp-action="Submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Submit</a>
```

2> use `Route Attribute` to route to the specified `view` .

Controller.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
      [Route("/Submit")]
      public IActionResult Submit()
      {
            return View("~/Views/Home/Submit.cshtml");
      }
 }
```

Test:

```
  https://localhost:44307/Submit

  https://localhost:44307/submit
```

The screenshot of result:
[image]

[image]

There are some articles it might help you to figure out Razor Pages and MVC.
[How Does Razor Pages Differ From MVC In ASP.NET Core?](https://exceptionnotfound.net/razor-pages-how-does-it-differ-from-mvc-in-asp-net-core/)
[Building Your .NET App - Razor Pages vs. ASP.NET MVC](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/razor-pages-vs-aspdotnet-mvc)